# Numbers not adding correctly in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to add a Twitter count number and a Feedburner count number but when I combine the two with basic addition, it fails!  If I get the valkues and print them seperatley it works fine, just will not let me add the two...

```
$twitCnt = twitter_subscribers(TWITTER_USERNAME);
$feedCnt = feed_subscribers(FEEDBURNER_USERNAME);
$totalCnt = $twitCnt + $feedCnt;

echo $totalCnt;
```

Assume that `$twitCnt` is = 2000 and `$feedCnt` is = 1000

Now when I try to add the 2 instead of getting `3000` I will get the `$feedCnt` value + 1 = `1001` instead of `3000`

I am currently stumped, If I print the `$twitCnt` and the `$feedCnt` they show the correct amounts, however when I add the 2 in my code, the `$twitCnt` is shown as = 1 instead of it's actual value.

Any ideas what would cause this?

---

Update after running `var_dump($twitCnt, $feedCnt)`

```
string(5) "3,000"
object(SimpleXMLElement)#238 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "1,000"
}
```

Also the Functions for getting the stats...

```
function twitter_subscribers($username = 'yourname'){
    $count = get_transient('twitter_count');
    if ($count != false){
        return $count;
    }else{
        $count = 0;         
        $url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name='. $username;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
        $count = $xml->followers_count;
        $count = (float) $count;
        $count = number_format($count);
        set_transient('twitter_count', $count, 21600); // 6 hour cache
        return $count;
    }
}

function feed_subscribers($username = 'yourname')
{
    $feed_url = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/' . $username;
    $count = get_transient('rss_count');
    if ($count != false)
        return $count;
    $count = 0;
    $data = wp_remote_get('http://feedburner.google.com/api/awareness/1.0/GetFeedData?uri=' .
        $feed_url . '');
    if (is_wp_error($data)) {
        return 'error';
    } else {
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($data);
        echo $body;
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($body);
        $status = $xml->attributes();
        if ($status == 'ok') {
            $count = $xml->feed->entry->attributes()->circulation;
        } else {
            $count = 300; // fallback number
        }
    }
    set_transient('rss_count', $count, 21600); // 6 hour cache//60*60*24

    return $count;
}
```

Comment: Show us the result of `var_dump($twitCnt); var_dump($feedCnt);`.

Comment: Please `var_dump($twitCnt, $feedCnt)` to check what they are first.

Comment: I have added the result of the `var_dump` above

Comment: var_dump() might just be PHP's greatest debug tool ;)

Comment: Don't use `number_format()` before you do any manipulation of numbers. Only use it when displaying them. Not sure where the comma is coming from in your feedburner `circulation` attribute. This number is not meant to be formatted according to the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first `$twitCnt` is a formatted string (I don't know why you format the value directly into the variable, since you need to compute that value prior to display it, you should only format it *when* displaying it). And `$feedCnt` is an object of type `SimpleXMLElement`.

To fix this, do not format `$twitCnt` but only when you display the value (ie. echo it) to the user. And fix this line `$count = $xml->feed->entry->attributes()->circulation;` so it returns a numeric value instead of an object.

** **Update** **

I took a small piece of code found [here](http://www.thinksynergy.co.uk/2009/03/18/converting-a-php-string-number-into-a-numeric-value/) and giving it to you as a solution to convert your formatted numbers to actual numeric values.

For instance, it will convert `1,200.123` into `1200.123`

```
function formattedStringToNumeric($str) {
  $a = array_pad(explode(".",str_replace(',','',$str)), 2, 0);            // Split the string, using the decimal point as separator
  $int = $a[0];                        // The section before the decimal point
  $dec = $a[1];                        // The section after the decimal point
  $lengthofnum=strlen($dec);            // Get the num of characters after the decimal point
  $divider="1";                        // This sets the divider at 1
  $i=0;
  while($i < ($lengthofnum)) {
    $divider.="0";                    // Adds a zero to the divider for every char after the decimal point
    $i++;
  }
  $divider=(int)$divider;                // Converts the divider (currently a string) to an integer
  return $int+($dec/$divider);        // compiles the total back as a numeric 
}
```

But why go complicated when you can simply do :

```
$value = (float) str_replace(',','',$string);
```

Comment: FYI, you need cast `SimpleXMLElement` to the data type required, eg `return (int) $count`. Not sure where the formatting on the feedburner count is coming from though

Comment: Great thanks everyone for the help, now I see the problem started once I got over the 1,000 mark because my code was adding the `,` before processing the numbers, I wouldn't of gotten this without the help here thanks

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

```
$count = $xml->feed->entry->attributes()->circulation;
```

[`SimpleXMLElement::attributes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) returns a SimpleXMLElement object, and so does fetching one of the properties, but you can cast to the expected data type just like you did here in the twitter function:

```
$count = $xml->followers_count;
$count = (float) $count;
```

So, cast to integer, float, or even string:

```
$count = (int) $xml->feed->entry->attributes()->circulation;
```

Answer (score 1):

ensure, that the variables are numbers.

```
$totalCnt = (int)$twitCnt + (int)$feedCnt;
```